# Считать несколько строк в одну переменную

Tags: java, строки, scanner

Подскажите плз, как реализовать следующую задачу:

Считать из стандартного потока (консоль) несколько строк в одну переменную

Т.е. в консоли пользователь пишет:

- Буря мглою, небокроет[нажимает Enter, курсор переходит на новую
  строку]
- Вихри снежные крутя[нажимает Enter, курсор переходит на новую
  строку]
- То как зверь она завоет[нажимает Enter, курсор переходит на    новую
  строку]
- То заплачет как дитя[нажимает Enter, курсор переходит    на новую
  строку]

Мне нужно в переменную типа String считать полностью все строки, включая символ переноса каретки.

Попробовал через Scaner:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(str);
```

Не могу сообразить как сделать так чтобы при нажатии Enter продолжалось считывание из потока.

В итоге в String должно записаться:
Буря мглою, небокроетВихри снежные крутяТо как зверь она завоетТо заплачет как дитя

А так как перенос каретки тоже должен считаться то при выводе переменной str должно быть выведено 4 строки

Comment: Вы считали одну строку, что Вам мешает повторить те же действия еще три раза? Как вариант можете сделать `String str =+ sc.nextLine();` , добавляя символ переноса каретки, еще три раза; Можно конечно придумать и более элегантное решение

Comment: Тут смысл в том что я не знаю сколько изначально будет строк. Может 4 а может 104, поэтому и хочу непрерывным потоком считать, чтобы уже потом распарсить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с завершением ввода по вводу пустой строки

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
String current = sc.nextLine();
while(!current.equals("")){
    list.add(current);
    current = sc.nextLine();
}
```

А потом делайте с `list` что хотите, хоть через `\n` склеивайте, хоть построчно выводите.

Comment: Спасибо, все оказалось просто )

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.nextLine() + "\n";
str += sc.nextLine() + "\n";
str += sc.nextLine() + "\n";
str += sc.nextLine() + "\n";
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: плюс ловите, но все же лучше более общий вариант распишите, с циклом хотя бы.

Comment: @kernel40 ну так читайте в цикле в массив, а потом хотите как массив оставьте, хотите - в строку склейте. Какое, кстати, условие завершения ввода?

Comment: условие завершения - пустая строка. Про цикл не совсем понятно. C условием цикла вроде ясно: while (!sc.nextLine().equals("")) { }. А в теле цикла как помещать в массив введенные данные?